# Como simular Zoom Pinça (pinch zoom) no Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, dev-tools

Estou trabalhando em uma interface que será mobile. Existe alguma forma de simular o Zoom Pinça *(pinch zoom)* no Chrome Dev Tools? Pelo menos a partir da versão 59 ou superior?

*OBS: Para quem ficou na dúvida, o Zoom pinça é aquele zoom que você faz na tela usando dois dedos.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem sim, é só você colocar o Chrome em modo dev com a tecla <kbd>F12</kbd> (você já deve saber disso), depois ativa o modo Device Toolbar, que deixará a tela responsiva ou <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, na tela click e segure o <kbd>Shift</kbd> e ele irá fazer o zoom in ou out a partir do ponto inicial do click que você deu.

Comment: Rapaz é isso mesmo, obrigado!